# Reference ManyToMany Field in Django Model Method

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am attempting to reference the ManyToMany connection between `Units` and `Add-Ons` in my code to enable a method that provides the price, but I seem to be unable to reference the relationship in a Model method, can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
class Unit(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('generate_unit_csv', 'can generate unit csv'),
        )
        unique_together = ['building', 'unit_number', 'property']


    add_ons = models.ManyToManyField(
         'properties.RentalAddOns', related_name='add_on_units')
    ...


    def get_add_on_price(self):
        total_price = 0
        # there is no self.add_on_units or self.add_ons
        for add_on in self.add_on_units:
            total_price += add_on.price
        return total_price
```

When I call the method I get an Attribute Error:

```
'Unit' object has no attribute 'add_on_units'
```

When I simple use `self.add_ons` I get:

```
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Use `self.add_ons.all()`

Comment: Ah hah @heemayl, super simple, I feel dumb now....thanks!

Comment: how do we reference a single column or attribute inside model ? e.g. `self.add_on_units.property`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've defined the field in this model, you need to refer to it as such. Also, you need to use the `all()` method on the resulting manager object to get all the related objects so that you can iterate over them:

```
self.add_ons.all()
```

And from the `RentalAddOns` model instance, you can refer all the `Unit` model instances as:

```
self.add_on_units.all()
```